# Show that $|μ|(C)=\sup_{\substack{f\in C_b\\|f|\le1\\\left.f\right|_{C^c}=0}}\mu f$ for all open $C$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a metric space and $\mu$ be a finite signed measure on $\mathcal B(E)$.

> I would like to show that$^1$ $$|\mu|(C)=\sup_{\substack{f\in C_b(E)\\|f|\le1\\\left.f\right|_{E\setminus C}=0}}\mu f\;\;\;\text{for all open }C\subseteq E\tag1.$$ Moreover, I would like to know whether there is a similar identity for $|\mu|(A)$ and closed $A\subseteq E$.

Note that "$\le$" in $(1)$ is clearly trivial. The other inequality should follow from the following two results:

---

**Lemma 1**: If $\nu$ is a finite signed measure on $\mathcal B(E)$, $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ and $\varepsilon>0$, then $$|\nu|(C\setminus A)<\varepsilon\tag2$$ for some closed $A\subseteq E$ and open $C\subseteq E$ with $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$.

**Lemma 2**: If $\emptyset\subset A\subseteq E$ and $C\subset E$ with $\overline A\subseteq C^\circ$, then there is a $f\in C_b(E)$ with $0\le1 f\le 1$ and \begin{align}\left.f\right|_A&=1\tag{3a}\\\left.f\right|_{E\setminus C}&=0.\tag{3b}\end{align}

---

Now let $C\subseteq E$ be open and $\varepsilon>0$. Let $E^{\pm}$ be a Hahn decomposition of $E$ wrt $\mu$ and $C^\pm:=C\cap E^\pm$. By Lemma 1, applied to both measures in the Jordan decomposition $\mu^\pm$ of $\mu$ individually, $$\pm\mu(C^\pm\setminus A^\pm)=\mu^\pm(C\setminus A)<\varepsilon\tag4$$ for some closed $A^\pm\subseteq E$ with $A^\pm\subseteq C^\pm\subseteq C$. (We may need to exclude the cases $A^\pm=\emptyset$ and $C^\pm=E$.)

Now, by Lemma 2, there is a $f^\pm\in C_b(E)$ with $0\le f^\pm\le 1$ and \begin{align}\left.f^\pm\right|_{A^\pm}&=1\tag{5a}\\\left.f^\pm\right|_{E\setminus C^\pm}&=0.\tag{5b}\end{align} Let $$g:=f^+-f^-.$$ Note that $g\in C_b(E)$ with $|g|\le1$ and \begin{align}\left.g\right|_{A^\pm}&=\pm1\tag{6a}\\\left.g\right|_{E\setminus C}&=0.\tag{6b}\end{align}

> **Question 1**: We are done if we can show that $\mu g>|\mu|(C)-2\varepsilon$. However, for some reason, I'm not able to obtain this inequality. How do we need to split the integral $$\mu g=\int_Cg\:{\rm d}\mu\tag7$$ in order to obtain this result?
>
> **Question 2**: Can we find a similar identity for $|\mu|(A)$ and closed $A\subseteq E$?

---

$^1$ $C_b(E)$ denotes the space of bounded continuous functions and $\mu f:=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu$.

Comment: For closed sets (1) fails even for positive measures : Take $\mu$ to be the delta measure at $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't expected that $(1)$ holds for closed sets. I'm just curious whether we are able to find a similar formula for closed sets which allows us to conclude $$\limsup_{t\in I}|\mu_t|(A)\le|\mu|(A)\;\;\;\text{for all closed }A\subseteq E,$$ assuming $\mu_t\to\mu$ weakly.

Comment: For a reference, this result has been generalized [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4573202/1019043).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a Hahn decomposition $E = E^{+}\sqcup E^{-}$. For any set, denote $C^{\pm} = C \cap E^{\pm}$. Now, we have
$|\mu|(C)= \mu(C^{+}) - \mu(C^{-})$.  Now take $A^{\pm} \subset C^{\pm}$,
, such that $|\mu|(C^{\pm}\backslash A^{\pm}) < \epsilon$ ( we assume some regularity here). Consider a continuous function $f^{\pm} $ defined on $E$ with values in $[0,1]$, and taking value $1$ on $A^{\pm}$, and $0$ on $A^{\mp}$. Now consider $ g= f^+- f^-$. Multiply it with a function with values in $[0,1]$, taking value $0$ on $E\backslash C$, and $1$ on $A^+\cup A^-$. So may assume from the beginning that $g$ is zero outside $C$. Now, we can see that the integral $\mu(g)$ is close to $|\mu|(C)$.

$\bf{Added:}$ We have
$$||\mu|(C)- \int_C g d\mu |= |\int_{C^+\backslash A} (1-g) d \mu + \int_{C^{-} \backslash B} (-1 - g) d\mu| \le 2 \epsilon + 2 \epsilon = 4\epsilon$$

Note: we can do this also for complex measures, or say for measures with values in some finite dimensional Hilbert space $E$. We then have to consider $\mu(f)$ for $f$ continuous with values in $E$ and $\|f\|\le 1$.  Instead of considering the Hahn decomposition, we consider the vector density $\rho$ (Radon-Nikodym) of $\mu$ with respect to $\|\mu\|$, which is a measurable $E$-valued function of constant absolute value $1$. Now we have to piece-wise interpolate this $\rho$, like above, but with more values.

$\bf{Added:}$

Some calculations about limits of measures
Consider a net of measures $\mu_t$ converging weakly to $\mu$. Then we have
$$\lim\inf_t |\mu_t|(U) \ge |\mu|(U)$$ for every $U$ open.

Assume that we have moreover
$$|\mu_t|(E)|\to |\mu|(E)$$

Consider $A = E\backslash U$ a closed set.

We have
$$\lim\sup_t |\mu_t|(A) = \lim \sup (|\mu_t|(E) - |\mu|(U)) =|\mu|(E) - \lim \sup |\mu_t|(U) \le |\mu|(E) - |\mu|(U)=|\mu|(A)$$

Conversely, if we have the inequality for the closed set $E$, since $E$ is also open, we must have $|\mu_t|(E)\to |\mu|(E)$.

However, we may have a strict inequality for some sequences.

Consider $E=[-1,1]$, $\phi\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ support in $[1-,1]$ negative on $(-\infty,0]$, positive on $[0\infty)$ and with $\int_{-1}^1 \phi(x) d x = 1$.  Then the sequence of measures $\mu_n(x) = n \phi_n(nx) dx$ converge to the delta measure $\delta_0$, but $|\mu_n| \to C\cdot \delta_0$, with $C = \int_{-1}^1|\phi(x)|dx> 1$

Comment: I'm sorry, but didn't you essentially repeat the arguments I've already presented in the question? And at the end, you've left out the only detail which I wasn't able to prove: Why does it hold $\mu g>|\mu|(C)-2\varepsilon$?

Comment: Yes, the idea to break the integral into parts is clear to me. But into which parts? Can you write it explicitly down (preferably with the symbols I've used in the question)? I'm sure it's obvious, but for some reason, I don't see it.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. The crucial step was to write $$|\mu|(C)-\int_Cg\:{\rm d}\mu=\int_{C\setminus A^+}1-g\:{\rm d}\mu^++\int_{C\setminus A^-}1+g\:{\rm d}\mu^-$$ which I didn't saw for some reason. By the result we've just shown it immediately follows that if $\mu_t\to\mu$, then $$\liminf_{t\in I}|\mu_t|(C)\ge|\mu|(C)\;\;\;\text{for all open }C\subseteq E.$$ Are we able to find a similar formula which allows us to conclude $$\limsup_{t\in I}|\mu_t|(A)\le|\mu|(A)\;\;\;\text{for all closed }A\subseteq E?$$

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Since $E$ is both open and closed, if your statement is true for $E$, then necessarily we have $|\mu_t|(E) \to |\mu|(E)$.  And conversely, from this, passing to complements, and the statement for open sets, we get the one for closed. So now it's all about $E$. This seems interesting.

Comment: Could you clarify which statement you are referring to when you write "your statement"? And can you state more explicitly what you're intending to obtain by passing to complements? Please note that I've asked a separate question for this: https://mathoverflow.net/q/380113/91890. Please let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: @0xbadf00d:  The answer whether you have the inequality for a general closed $A$?  Not in general. Since for the total set $E$ we could have the strict inequality $\lim |\mu_n|(E) > |\mu|(E)$. See the last edit.

Comment: Thank you for the addendum. If you already know that $$\lim\inf_t |\mu_t|(U) \ge |\mu|(U)$$ for all open $U$ and you additionally have $$|\mu_t|(E)|\to |\mu|(E),$$ then you can also apply the Portmanteau theorem to $|\mu_t|$ to obtain $$\limsup_{t\in I}|\mu_t|(A)\le|\mu|(A)\;\;\;\text{for all closed }A\subseteq E.$$

Comment: Recently, I had a related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433951/vague-convergence-confusion-about-the-regularity-of-a-signed-radon-measure-and/433987#433987). Could you elaborate on some "...some regularity here".

Comment: @Analyst:  Yeah, it is about the inner regularity of the measure $|\mu|$ it seems. Apriori it may not be regular, but it is so in many cases ( like locally compact with countable basis ... I wrote once something about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582147/a-locally-finite-borel-measure-on-a-locally-and-sigma-compact-metric-space-is/1582479#1582479).

Comment: Ahh "...locally compact with countable basis" is exactly [the case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570444/every-locally-compact-separable-metric-space-is-a-radon-space) when $X$ is locally compact and separable. Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: @Analyst: Thank you for all the pointers. Right, for metric spaces it seems that is equivalent.  It's getting clearer for me too :-)

Comment: I don't know if you are interested, but your result has been generalized [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4573202/1019043).

Comment: @Analyst: The equality  $|\mu|(U) = \sup_{\ldots} \mu(f)$ for finite measures implies $|\mu|(U) \le \lim \inf |\mu_i|(U)$ whenever $\mu_i$ converges weakly to $\mu$.  So if we can prove the above expression for $|\mu|$, $|\mu|_i$ then we are OK. It seems it has to do with the regularity of the measure(s), which can be proved if the total space $X$ is OK.  Definitely interesting!

Comment: I have just asked a further generalization [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434328/a-generalization-about-the-density-of-mathcal-c-cx-e-in-mathcal-l-p-x).