# Every locally compact separable metric space is a Radon space

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

Recently, I have come across [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4568571/1019043) about weak convergence of measures. I'm trying to see why the usual hypothesis is "$X$ is a locally compact separable metric space". Then I come across below result, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** Let $(E, d)$ be a locally compact separable metric space. Then $E$ is a [Radon space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure#Radon_spaces).

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**Proof:** Since $E$ is locally compact and separable metric space, [there exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305348/let-e-d-be-a-metric-space-then-x-is-second-countable-if-and-only-if-x-i) a countable basis $(U_n)$ such that $\overline{U_n}$ is compact for every $n$. Let
$$
K_m := \bigcup_{n=1}^m \overline{U_n} \quad \forall m \in \mathbb N.
$$

Then $K_m$ is compact and $\bigcup_m K_m = E$.

Because $\mu$ is inner regular, it suffices to prove that $\mu$ is tight on every closed subset $B$ of $E$. The claim then follows immediately because
$$
B = \bigcup_m (E \cap K_m),
$$
and because $E \cap K_m$ is a compact subset of $E$. This completes the proof.