# If $X$ is locally compact separable, then $\mathcal C_c(X)$ is dense in $\big (\mathcal L_p, \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal L_p} \big)$ for all $p\in [1,\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space, $\mu$ a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $X$, and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Let $\mathcal L_p := \mathcal L_p (X, \mu, E)$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal L_p}$ be its *semi-norm*. Here we use the [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). Let $\mathcal C_c(X)$ be the space of all $E$-valued continuous functions on $X$ with compact supports.

To fix a logical mistake in [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572315/let-x-be-locally-compact-separable-and-mu-n-overset-rightharpoonup-mu), I have come across this result, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** If $X$ is locally compact separable, then $\mathcal C_c(X)$ is dense in $\big (\mathcal L_p, \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal L_p} \big)$ for all $p \in [1, \infty)$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**Proof:** We need the following results, i.e.,

- **Lemma 1:** The space $\mathcal S := \mathcal S(X, \mu, E)$ of simple functions is dense in $\big (\mathcal L_p, \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal L_p} \big)$ for all $p \in [1, \infty)$. [Prop 4.8 in Amann's *Analysis III*]
- [Lemma 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570444/every-locally-compact-separable-metric-space-is-a-radon-space) Let $X$ be a locally compact separable metric space. Then $X$ is a [Radon space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure#Radon_spaces).
- [Lemma 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914363/open-sets-with-compact-closure-containing-a-given-compact-set) Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological space. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$ and $U$ an open subset of $X$ such that $K \subset U$. Then there is an open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $K \subset V \subset \overline V \subset U$ and $\overline V$ is compact.

Let $\mathcal X$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. By **Lemma 1** and Minkowski's inequality, it suffices to approximate the map $e1_B$ with $e\in E \setminus \{0\}$ and $B \in \mathcal X$ such that $\mu(B) < \infty$ by a map $f \in \mathcal C_c(X)$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. By **Lemma 2**, there is a compact subset $K$ and an open subset $O$ of $X$ such that $K \subset B \subset O$ and $\mu(O \setminus K) < \varepsilon$.

By **Lemma 3**, then there is an open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $K \subset V \subset \overline V \subset O$ and $\overline V$ is compact. By [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma#Formal_Statement), there is a continuous $h:X \to [0, 1]$ such that $h(K)=1$ and $h(X \setminus V) = 0$. Let $f (x) := e h (x)$ for all $x\in X$. Then
$$
\operatorname{supp} f = \operatorname{supp} h \subset \overline V.
$$

Hence $f$ is compactly supported. We have
$$
\| eh-e1_B\|_{\mathcal L_p} \le |e|^p \mu (O \setminus K) < |e|^p \varepsilon.
$$

The proof then completes by taking the limit $\varepsilon \to 0^+$.